# gentoo: How make emerge better use of more cores?

Tags: gentoo

I have Intel Atom N2800 (weak, but handy Aspire One D270, still enought for the work I use it for), but updates are really slow (like **days**).

I use `MAKEOPTS=" -j5 "` in `/etc/make.conf` and and `emerge -DuNqv world` and it sometimes goes to `Load avg 5.0 5.0 5.0` or so, but usually it is just somewhere around 1.5 only.

Is there a way to make it be more time more paralel (and so faster)?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a hardware question?

Comment: I think, it is more `configuration` question about gentoo and its package manager. I mentioned hardware for there may be some restriction going from that. But my goal is to have the package manager use the hardware as much as possible to have done things faster - so maybe there are some other options to say it run packages in paralel or otherwise use more cores/threads even if the package just compiling is single threaded or so

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some things you can do to speed up portage, but often times these tweaks can have other side-effects without careful attention.

You can manipulate the intended loading by using `--load-average=##.##` in conjunction with `--jobs=##` on the command line. Replace the #'s with numbers. You can also make this and most other values (semi)permanent by adding `EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS="--jobs=## --load-average=##.##"` to make.conf. There is a  [decent article](https://www.preney.ca/paul/archives/341) about using these values with real-world application. What isn't in the article is how to properly get around build failures due to a customized make.conf. If you want to make these settings global (make.conf), you should also understand how to bypass those settings with custom environment for specific packages. See [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/portage/package.env).

Some other notes (good and bad) on speeding up portage:

1) Enable parallel_fetch in your make.conf by adding / editing `FEATURES="${FEATURES} parallel-fetch"`. This entry will allow downloading packages while it builds the current one. It doesn't really answer your question as such, but it's one of the least invasive portage "speed-ups".

2) Enable ccache. Install the ccache package, and add `ccache` to FEATURES like in #1. You will also need to define `CCACHE_SIZE` and `CCACHE_DIR`. Though it started out as a great idea, a lot of people have cooled on the benefits of ccache. It has been known to cause issues with some packages, and there are many reports that claim it can degrade compilation performance more often than speeding things up. I can't speak for how correct it is, but many of the points addressed [in this article warning about using ccache](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2010/07/debunking-ccache-myths-redux) are common belief.

3) ReNice emerge. You can define the niceness increment by adding `PORTAGE_NICENESS=-#`. The value of this number is added to the default process value. By making it negative, you will reduce the niceness of emerge processes. Be very careful with this setting as it will apply to subprocesses as well. With some packages having multiple subprocesses, this could get dicey in a hurry.

**Final note - some of these features depend on your portage version**. I mention this since you said you are editing /etc/make.conf, which is the old location. Newer portage versions have migrated config files to /etc/portage.  If you have a make.conf in both places, the file in /etc/portage will supersede the one in /etc.

Comment: The part of `--jobs` and `--load-average` being  `emerge` (not `make`) parameters was exactly, what I was looking for (and somehow missed / did not understood) in documentation. I will also use ReNicing, as I am running it over night usually and nothing else is supposed to run (or at least run fast - some widgets shows something and such, but they are not important). Ccache is probabelly not good option for me, as I do large updates (like world after half a year), so chance for a cache hit is probably really low.